# Using an insert statement in an if ... then (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

(Using SQL Server 2008R2)
I've got 2 values in a record in a table that will never contain data at the same time.  I want to insert a record into 1 of 2 junction tables depending on which field has data.

```
SELECT @val1 = [propVal1ID]
        ,@val2 = [propVal2ID]
FROM [proposalPackage] 
WHERE [proposalPackageID] = @proposal

IF @val1 > 0
    INSERT INTO [jTable1]
                ([projectID]
                ,[value1_ID]
                ,[subValue1_ID]
                ,[priority]
                ,[isActive])
            SELECT
                @project as projectID
                ,@val1 as [value1_ID]
                ,[subValue1ID] as [subValue1_ID]
                ,1 as [priority]
                ,'true' as [isActive]
            FROM [proposalPackage]
            WHERE [proposalPackageID] = @proposal
ELSE IF @val2 > 0
    INSERT INTO [jTable2]
                ([projectID]
                ,[value2_ID]
                ,[priority]
                ,[isActive])
            SELECT
                @project as projectID
                ,@val2 as [value2_ID]
                ,1 as [priority]
                ,'true' as [isActive]
            FROM [proposalPackage]
            WHERE [proposalPackageID] = @proposal
END IF;
```

Everything seems to parse until it gets to the "end if;" when it gives me a "syntax error."

I tried a CASE statement but that failed miserably...  CASE only seems appropriate when checking the same variable/field value.

Question 1: What is the proper syntax following the end/end if?  Everywhere I look, it says to use a semi-colon (;).
Question 2: Is there a better way to catch this mouse?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Show us the error message. Also, just a reminder that 0 does not equal NULL

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `END IF`.  It has statement blocks delimited by `BEGIN`/`END`.

Comment: Error message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 43
Incorrect syntax near 'END'
Also, values are set to 0 in DECLARE statement...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ... that was too easy... thanks.  How do I make your comment my answer?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't use `END IF` to denote the end of an `IF` block, you need to wrap the content inside a `BEGIN`/`END`:

```
IF @val1 > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT ... --something
END
ELSE IF @val2 > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT ... --something else
END
```

Alternatively, since you only have a single statement inside your `IF` blocks, you can omit the `BEGIN`/`END` completely, but I'm not fond of that as it can lead to difficult to spot bugs.